# Generating offline documentation for Spring projects

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-social, spring-ldap, spring-session, asciidoctor

As part of familiarizing myself with the gauntlet of frameworks and functionalities provided by Spring, I often download their PDF documentation to read offline. For instance, the core Spring Framework documentation is [over 900 pages](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/pdf/spring-framework-reference.pdf).

However, I noticed that there are quite a few top-level Spring projects that don't have their equivalent offline/PDF documentation. Full list:

[Spring Cloud](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.M2/)

[Spring Social](https://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/)

[Spring LDAP](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/reference/)

[Spring Session](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/)

[Spring Flo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-flo/wiki)

I remembered reading somewhere that Spring uses AsciiDoctor to generate their documentation. So, my question is, what is the fastest way one can one go about converting the "htmlsingle" or "html5" online documentation to PDFs for offline viewing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the normal `Ctrl + P` and then `Save as PDF` in Chrome renders the webpage for Spring Cloud as a proper PDF, in the same format/layout as the "official" PDF docs for the other Spring projects.

Thanks to Github user https://github.com/dsyer for providing the hint on the Spring Cloud Gitter.